# How to open Toplevel window in new thread?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a function that creates new Toplevel window like that:

```
def createPreview():
    win = Toplevel(root)
    ...
```

There is no problem when I run this function like that:

```
createPreview()
```

But when I try to use new thread, program is freezing. I use this code:

```
_thread.start_new_thread(createPreview)
```

How to fix this problem?

I have one necessary condition: this new thread must be killed when I'll exit from main program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a toplevel window in another thread. Tkinter is single threaded and should be run only in the main thread. You cannot create widgets in a separate thread.